# How many bytes of extra memory does it take for virtual functions?

Tags: c++, memory, virtual-functions

There are all kinds of cases from simple to complex structures of virtual functions. What factor determines the number of extra memory it required? For example

```
class A            {virtual void F() {}   };
class B : public A {virtual void F() {}   };
```

How many more memory does A and B require compare to classes without virtual functions? Another example with 2 virtual functions,

```
class A            {virtual void F() {}   virtual void G() {}   };
class B : public A {virtual void F() {}   virtual void G() {}   };
```

and example 3

```
class A            {virtual void F() {};   virtual void G() {}  };
class B : public A {virtual void F() {}                         };
```

[--------------- Add More Interesting questions ------------------]

1. Does every virtual method have a virtual method table? If so, I think for a class (not object, right? I think the VPTR is static.) with a number of virtual method requires a number of VPTRs, each for a virtual method. Right?
2. Is it possible to build just one table for all virtual methods and put only one VPTR in a class?
3. And I think the calling speed of virtual functions should be faster than manual ifs since the direct VPTR is used. Right?

[--------------- A Test ----------------]

I did a test and show my results with both VS2010 and intel c++ compiler.

```
struct A
{
    static int s_i;
    int i;
    virtual void F()    {i+=1;}
    virtual void G()    {i+=2;}
};

struct B
    : public A
{
    int j;
    virtual void F()    {i+=3;}
    virtual void G()    {i+=4;}

    virtual void H()    {i+=5;}
};

struct C
    : public B
{
    virtual void F()    {i+=6;}

    virtual void H()    {i+=7;}
};

TEST(MemoryForVirtualMethod)
{
    CHECK_EQUAL(sizeof(A), 8);
    CHECK_EQUAL(sizeof(B), 12);
    CHECK_EQUAL(sizeof(C), 12);
}
```

From the results, my conclusions are

(1) For each object with virtual functions, one (hidden pointer of) VPTR is added.

(2) Foe each class, a virtual method table is built for all virtual methods of the class.

(3) Putting the VPTR in object is to implement the dynamic dispatch since the class referred may not be the dynamic class.

(4) The implementation is efficient in calling (faster than manual ifs) but sacrifices some memory.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This will depend on your compiler and platform. Which ones are you interested in?

Comment: vs2010 or intel c++, Thanks.

Comment: How exactly does this information matter to you? It should not! If you need dynamic dispatch you simply will have to use `virtual` there is no Q of overhead here.You only pay for what you use.You use a functionality you pay the cost.Nothing more nothing less.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: Just curious, how many compilers do you know that __do not use vtable approach__?

Comment: @AlokSave: It may matter. For instance, you may remove one level of indirection by not using vtable and increasing object's memory footprint. And, after all, knowing details is great anyway. The ignorant approach is not the best.

Comment: for Q1, there are specifiers that can remove vtables (say for base classes that will never be instantiated), in MSVC, see `__declspec(novtable)`

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Can you do that and rely conclusively that your program is portable across all implementations? No, not even if all implementations use vtable or vptr mechanism because you cannot generalize all implementations to use the exact same number of vtables. So no it doesn't matter.

Comment: @AlokSave: Yes, you can. There is nothing not portable in using a function pointer instead of a virtual function.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Feel free to. Not necessary everyone agrees with your pre-optimization ideas though.I certainly don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since virtual functions are *typically* implemented as a [virtual method table (vtable)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), I am guessing `O(number of virtual functions)` per `class` and 1 extra pointer per `object`. Not as exact as you want, but should give a rough idea.
As @AlokSave mentions, there are many other subtleties which are very compiler specific and may not be consistent enough to estimate.

> Typically, the compiler creates a separate vtable for each class. When an object is created, a pointer to this vtable, called the virtual table pointer, vpointer or VPTR, is added as a hidden member of this object

Source : [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)

The number of functions you override (as in your examples) is (im guessing) irrelevent, except when the function to be called can safely be determined at compile time, in which case it *might* be treated as a static dispatch function (`G()` in your 2nd example). This is also up to the compiler.

> compilers usually avoid using vtables whenever the call can be resolved at compile time.

Finally, The cost of virtual function is likely to be harder on speed than memory..

Comment: *"Since virtual functions are implemented as a vtable"* most likely though not necessarily.This is completely implementation defined detail. Moreover, whether there is one vtable per class or more varies from each implementation to another. Eventhough vtable and vpointer mechanism is the most common way of implementing dynamic dispatch the number of vtables involved is not a consistent detail.

Comment: @AlokSave fixed that, I could swear there was a typically in my head when I wrote that :P